# Trouble deploying release version of Xamarin.Android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I'm getting the following error when the app finishes installing on the emulator using Xamarin Release run tool.

```
GREF GC Threshold: 1800

Unhandled Exception:
System.Net.WebException: Error: NameResolutionFailure
  at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at CallRestService.Activity1.<OnCreate>m__0 (IAsyncResult ar) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at System.Net.WebAsyncResult.CB (System.Object unused) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

The emulator is running Android 2.3.3, and the Debug build ran from Xamarin compiler works just fine.

Any hint on why this is happening and how to solve this problem?

Comment: `when the app finishes installing on the emulator...` Do you get this error before you run the app, or do you mean you hit run at the end of installation and then get the error?

Comment: I mean, when the app is prompted tu run on the simulator, right after it is installed.

Comment: Actually, I just fixed this error. I had to add the Android Manifest to the project on the Android Application preferences of the solution, and check the "Internet" box under the Required Permissions section of the panel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Had the same issue. Solved by adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` to the manifest.

Comment: I have Internet permission set but still getting same error.